# R Shiny: Background color changes with browser size

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I tried to customize the colors of a Shiny app. The minimal example with this code

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
tags$head(
    tags$style(
        HTML(
            '.skin-black .main-sidebar  {color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #9A373C;}
            .skin-black .main-header .navbar  { background-color: #ffffff;}
            .skin-black .span12 { background-color: #ffffff;}'
        )
    )
)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body,skin = "black")
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

generates an App that has a white header when the browser windows is large and a black/white header when the browser window is small.

[image]

What can I do in order to get it always white?

I am asking because I place a logo in the top left rectangular it looks awful when the background color gets black just because someone is looking at the app in a smaller window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets you where you want, but I did  all of it by inspecting the styles of the relevant elements, and I'm afraid that's what you need to do to in these situations - there isn't a better answer than just trial and error...

Hope it helps!

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            HTML(
           '.skin-black .main-sidebar  {color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #9A373C;}
            .skin-black .span12 { background-color: #ffffff;}
            .skin-black .main-header .navbar  { background-color: #ffffff;}
            .skin-black .main-header > .logo { background-color: #ffffff;}
            .skin-black .main-header > .logo:hover { background-color: #ffffff;}
            .skin-black .main-header .logo, .skin-black .main-header .navbar { transition: color 0s; }'
            )
        )
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body,skin = "black")
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I am just wondering where you get this information from. There are many tutorials on the Shiny website but they are superficial.

Comment: Sure thing! Yeah, the Shiny website is not where you should look for how to customize your website using HTML CSS or JS... Shiny has a few very good out-of-the box solutions, but then it's back to good old manual tweaking. From a quick online search, I found [this helpful tutorial](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/) that teaches you how to inspect and tweak a page until you get the look you want. Then just inject that CSS into your app using `tags$head( tags$style(HTML( ... )))`